# Jmeter loop according to multivalued user define variable

Tags: loops, jmeter

In my thread group, I need to execute "Start Episode and Finish Episode" HTTP requests

HTTP request

[image]

according to the "EPISODE_SLUG" parameter, which means need to execute the above two HTTP requests according to the episode counts include in the "EPISODE_SLUG"

Episode slug

[image]

the number of values of "EPISODE_SLUG" change from time to time

Please suggest me a method to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there are better options for extracting the `EPISODE_SLUG` so you could iterate them using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller), however if you did your best and ended up with the above setup - you can go for something like:

1. There is `EPISODE_COUNT` variable so you can put your requests under the Loop Controller and set the "Loop Count" to the `${EPISODE_COUNT}`
2. You can refer the "current episode" inside the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) using the following [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('EPISODE_SLUG').replace('['\,'').replace(']'\,'').split('\,')[vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int],)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot the above groovy function is working

Comment: Actually, I need to pass this episode_slug in a post request inside the loop controller, in this scenario, the second index -  "BeadsAddition5" as in the example does not pick in the second iteration, and in some scenarios one episode returns like this "EPISODE_SLUG=[BeadsAddition5]" any idea to handle this scenario